# JWT Invalid Signatures in .NET libraries

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I am currently struggling with creating signatures with any .net library to access Twitch api endpoints. The jwt.io page always says the signature is invalid when I copy paste my generated jwt there. When I edit the secret the signature is obviously adjusted and when I use the adjusted jwt I can make the Twitch api call without a problem. When I use my generated jwt I always end up with a 401 authentication failed.

I tried pretty much all of the .net libraries now and all of them generate a wrong signature for HS256… I am not sure what I do wrong since I am new to JWT and couldn’t find anything that points me to the right direction. Here is my code to generate the jwt using the jwt.net library (https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt). Would highly appreciate if someone could help me with this.

```
        var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
           { "exp", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(360).ToUnixTimeSeconds()},
           { "user_id", "668312333"},
           { "role", "external"},
        };
        var secret = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String("MY SHARED EXTENSION SECRET FROM TWITCH"));

        IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm(); // symmetric
        IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
        IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
        IJwtEncoder encoder = new JwtEncoder(algorithm, serializer, urlEncoder);
        
        var token = encoder.Encode(payload, secret);
```

Comment: one thing that jumps out, is your turning your secret into a string via UTF8,  try just doing ```var secret = Convert.FromBase64.....```

Comment: @KeithNicholas OMG I am actually dumb haha, or blind. This was it xD Thank you so much! If you want to post this as answer I will gladly mark it as solution! Thank you!

Comment: easy mistake to make, in this case the string should have worked, but I think there is a mismatch in the encoding and decoding to string.   It's just the byte array is actually the desired form of the secret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set the secret to be a byte array as that is what is needed by the underlying library :-

```
var secret = Convert.FromBase64String("MY SHARED EXTENSION SECRET FROM TWITCH");
```